# Ansible: register both job id and exit code

Tags: ansible

I am running an async loop in ansible;

I want to be able to register both the `shell` return code on each iteration as also (forcefully) the job ids to later poll the `async` tasks;

here is my current approach that allows me only to register everything needed for the `async` requirement

```
  - name: some_tests.yml -> Run the tests
    shell: some test command
    args:
      chdir: "test"
    async: 10000
    poll: 0
    loop: "{{ test_files.stdout_lines }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: "item"
    register: async_results


  - name: tests.yml -> Await  test completion
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ async_result_item.ansible_job_id }}"
    loop: "{{ async_results.results }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: "async_result_item"
    register: async_poll_results
    until: async_poll_results.finished
    retries: 100
```

How can I have access to the `rc` of each `shell` execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible "to register both the shell return code on each iteration as also (forcefully) the job ids to later poll the async tasks". The "async" task leaves without waiting for "shell" to finish. You'll have to take care of the results inside the "shell" script. Log to a file for example.

The rc codes and other registered attributes should be in *async_poll_results*.