# ansible.builtin.shell not working with disown and weird output redirection

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ssh, ansible, remote-server

I'm having a hard time understanding Ansible's overall remote behaviour.

I'm referring to all ansible.builtin.command and ansible.builting.shell modules.

It seems not to collet any output for scripts put in the background and disowned.

It seems to fail properly disown jobs (although `nohup` seems to work just fine, beside redirections -- so still there is a problem of loosing the whole background job's output).

I want to install a python templated script on multiple remote machines, run it and detach from Ansible's connection so that it runs in the background (as it's a blocking call listening on TCP port).
The python script is a couple of imports, print statements and then call to a `server.start()`, which is a blocking listening on a TCP port.

I wrote this task:

```
 - name: start services  # not working clearly 
    ansible.builtin.shell:
      executable: /bin/bash
      cmd: | 
        python3 <<-'EOF' &
        {{ lookup("ansible.builtin.template", "../scripts/server_start.tmpl", template_vars={"service": item}) }}
        EOF
        disown -h %1
    loop: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].services}}"
```

which does not work at all, as:

- output (any print() statements) from my python script is never captured by ansible -- although I thought that after calling disown only stdin is being detached,
- the script gets killed alongside Ansible process -- it does not preserve on remote machine

Can anyone give some logical explanation for this? I have tested it locally and it works as expected.
I have even tested the script locally by running `/bin/bash -c 'python3 <<-'EOF' ...'`, as that's how it's executed by ansible, I suppose. I have even tested it via SSH and still works. What is it with Ansible that it looses the output and does not correctly disown the job?

As a side note, Ansible captures the output correctly if I omit the blocking `server.start()` call. I have replaced `server.start()` call with a long `sleep()` and it does not work neither.

Comment: You are using a screwdriver to hammer a nail. Ansible is made to provision servers, not to withstand long running processes. You probably want a systemd unit and a service to achieve your end result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect running in the background to do. What return code do you expect ansible to receive and how would it be useful?

Comment: In addition to @β.εηοιτ.βε comment, if you still have a legitimate use case (which does not seem to be the case here) to run something for a long time on the target, use an [async process](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε What I had described is just a part of an initialisation phase of my remote, distributed testing framework. I am **intentionally** using Ansible as I want to  configure multiple remote machines in parallel. I want to avoid creating systemd units, as I am not sure whether all machines under test will be system-based. `
I can do workarounds, I asked the question in order to understand what is going on and the reason behind this behaviour. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into similar troubles with processes spawned remotely using Ansible: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33410.
It seems that there is a re-occuring problem between Ansible's  versions which results in killing all child processes upon terminating remote connection. *This seems to answer most of my doubts.*

I have changed the task to use `nohup` and python script to use logger with a file handler (as I mentioned in the original post, redirection of script's stdout did not work).

Comment: I am accepting my own answer as it directly  addresses my problem with a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding Ansible's overall remote behaviour

**Q: "*What is it with Ansible that it looses the output and does not correctly `disown` the job? ... Can anyone give some logical explanation for this?*"**

It seems that assumptions made are not correct in this case.

> ***I'm referring to all `ansible.builtin.command` and `ansible.builting.shell` modules.***

These modules are not mentioned as remote or interactive shells like in your SSH session. See [How does Ansible work?](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/automation/learning-ansible-tutorial#:%7E:text=Ansible%20works%20by%20connecting%20to,and%20removes%20them%20when%20finished.)

> ***It seems not to collcet any output for scripts put in the background and disowned.***

Right, that seems to be the expected behavior here. According [Introduction to modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/modules_intro.html) and [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *Ansible executes each module, usually on the remote managed node, and collects return values.*

and

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable ...*

therefore such behavior is not implemented. And regarding

> ***It seems to fail properly `disown` jobs (although `nohup` seems to work just fine, beside redirections -- so still there is a problem of loosing the whole background job's output)***

you may see also what is the [difference between `nohup`, `disown` and `&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/266568).

As already mentioned within the comments there is only the possibility is to [run concurrently: `poll = 0`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0) for long running tasks.

> *If you want to run multiple tasks in a playbook concurrently, use `async` with `poll` set to 0. When you set `poll: 0`, Ansible starts the task and immediately moves on to the next task without waiting for a result.*

However, it will not be possible to [register both, `job_id` and `rc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160267/6771046).

**Further Reading**

which might help to understand the issue

- [How can I get the output of an Ansible play as it is being run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341703/6771046)